# Introduce an additional base type in an exception hierarchy in C++?

Tags: c++, exception, multiple-inheritance

We have a base situation that looks as as follows:

```
// 3rd party lib:

namespace ns3p {
  class OperationException : public std::exception; // yes, no `virtual` here
}

// our code:

// wrapper with additional information to the ns3p::OperationException
class ModuleOpException : public ns3p::OperationException;

// our catch sites:
// mostly:
catch (ModuleOpException const& ex) { ...
// but sometimes:
catch (ns3p::OperationException const& ex) { ...
```

Now, this grew to include additional exceptions, all derived from the `ModuleOpException` that *do not* have anything to do with any error from the 3rd party lib, but are just thrown in the same context where stuff from the 3rd party lib is used.

```
// This indirectly derives from ns3p::OperationException, even though 
// there is *no* underlying OperationException at all. It just thrown "stand alone"
// and caught by ModuleOpException& :
class InvalidXYZException : public ModuleOpExcpetion;
```

We have now thought about "inverting" the hierarchy to better reflect the actual situation and do so with (initially) minimal impact on other code.

We plan to do this:

```
// new base exception type:
class ModuleBaseException : public virtual std::exception;

// changed to derive both from our base type as well as the 3rd party type:
class ModuleOpException : public virtual ModuleBaseException, public virtual ns3p::OperationException;

// only derives from the base type:
class InvalidXYZException : public virtual ModuleBaseException;

// all catch sites change the catch of `ModuleOpException` to:
catch (ModuleBaseException const& ex) { ...
// and leave the catch ns3p::OperationException alone
```

**This should work (should it?)**, except that I'm not sure how much the non-virtual inheritance from `std::exception` of the 3rd part exception type can mess things up. I *think* we're safe [as long as noone tries to `catch(std::exception const&)` in which case the catch would fail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1605852/321013) to bind at runtime because the conversion is ambiguous.

Does this seem like a viable solution? Or is it a "really bad idea" to try to integrate a `non-virtual-std::exception` type with a hierarchy like above?

<sub>Note: There is zero chance (as in `0.00%`) that we can ever change the 3rd party lib to derive "properly" with `virtual` from std::exception.</sub>

---

- Of course, if any `catch(ns3p::OperationException&)` in the previous version "accidentally" caught an `InvalidXYZExecption` this will break now, but that'd be acceptable.

Comment: Why do you need so many exception classes, and why do you need ModuleOpException to derive from a 3rd party library exception class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The try...catch should happen at a place where the exception is going to be properly handled, or if an exception will be modified at this point and rethrown.

The purpose of using different exception classes is to handle them in a different manner. (My opinion is that this is a bad idea, switching on some kind of code would be better, and you are likely to change your action based on the type only in rare circumstances, like retrying a request if the error is transient).

In any case, the 3rd party library, I assume, is used to help implement your own libraries. The users of your libraries do not want to know about exceptions from the library you are using to implement.

Therefore you should abstract this from the user of your libraries by catching any of them and re-throwing them as your own, in a way the user would expect.

Exceptions thrown from your library are as much a part of the "contract" as return values from your functions.

Thus the users would expect to potentially catch a ModuleBaseException or a ModuleOpException but not an ns3p::OperationException.

Your own code should catch them, probably convert them to your ModuleOpException type and throw that instead.

Comment: So, essentially you're saying: Do not derive from the 3rd party type"?

Comment: In this instance I can't see what you gain by doing so. You are using a 3rd party library, they are not using your code and nobody is catching their exception types here other than you.

Comment: Thinking about it, *not* deriving from the 3rd party at all, probably *is* the best solution. Thanks.

Comment: And while I'm at it, and since you wrote "... to handle them in a different manner. (My opinion is that this is a bad idea ..." you might like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27825133/321013) totally unrelated piece :-)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it should work. C++ specification says :

*A handler is a match for an exception object of type E if ... the handler is of type cv T or cv T& and T is an unambiguous public base class of E or ...*

and *The handlers for a try block are tried in order of appearance.*

So as long as you catch `ModuleBaseException` before `ns3p::OperationException` any exception deriving from `ModuleBaseException` should be caught in correct handler even if it also derives from `ns3p::OperationException`.

The only problem is that all methods and fields from std::exception will be duplicated in your exception classes and you should always qualify them as coming from ModuleBaseException to avoid ambiguities. You should probably use a common utility to process the exception that would be used in all the handlers.

Comment: On a syntax level or whatever it will work. However in this instance I think the user is getting a bit confused about the hierarchy and what is catching what exception

Answer (score 1):

When deriving from an existing exception hierarchy you have multiple inheritance (one for your own and one for the existing hierarchy). To avoid ambiguity you can pass and keep a pointer to the existing hierarchy:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>

// Error
//=============================================================================

/// Base class for all exceptions in a library.
/// \NOTE The constructor requires a std::exception as argument
class Error
{
    // Construction
    // ============

    public:
    virtual ~Error() noexcept {};

    protected:
    Error(std::exception& exception)
    :   m_exception(&exception)
    {}


    // Element Access
    // ==============

    public:
    const char* msg() const { return m_exception->what(); }

    // Cast
    // ====

    protected:
    template <typename Derived>
    static std::exception& cast(Derived& derived) {
        return static_cast<std::exception&>(derived);
    }

    private:
    std::exception* m_exception;
};


// Runtime Errors
// ============================================================================

/// A Runtime Error.
class ErrorRuntime : public std::runtime_error, public Error
{
    public:
    explicit ErrorRuntime(const std::string& msg)
    :   std::runtime_error(msg), Error(cast(*this))
    {}
};

// Test
// ====

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    try {
        throw ErrorRuntime("Hello Exception");
    }
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        try {
            std::cerr << "std::exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
            throw;
        }
        catch(const Error& e) {
            try {
                // No what here
                std::cerr << "Error: " << e.msg() << "\n";
                throw;
            }
            catch(const ErrorRuntime& e) {
                std::cerr << "ErrorRuntime: " << e.what() << "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if you have a third party library, you might hide all exceptions of that library (as mentioned by other). The costs of hiding are two layers for incoming and outgoing exceptions.